# Does the Scout's Ambush Master feature require a successful attack to activate it?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, rogue, combat-advantage

The Scout subclass of the Rogue includes the 13th-level feature "Ambush Master" which says:

> Starting at 13th level, you excel at leading ambushes and acting first in a fight.
>
> You have advantage on initiative rolls. In addition, the first creature you hit during the first round of a combat becomes easier for you and others to strike; attack rolls against that target have advantage until the start of your next turn.

Because this says "the first creature you ***hit***," does this mean you must make a *successful* attack roll in the first round of combat *before* any advantage will apply? Or does "hit" in this context apply to your very first attack roll because all that's needed is for the attempt to be made?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### There is no “first creature you hit” until after you have hit something.

You have made the correct observation in your question when you write “you must make a successful attack roll in the first round of combat before any advantage will apply”. If you have not yet hit a creature this combat, *there is no “first creature you hit”*. You have to hit something for there to be a “first creature you hit”. So the Ambush Master feature does not give advantage on attack rolls until after you have successfully hit a target.

Comment: Doesn’t real make it easier for you to hit, does it?

Comment: @NautArch It does if you have a second attack, which as a rogue, requires CBX, TWF, or multiclassing.

Comment: The target could trigger an attack of opportunity after that first hit, which would be made with advantage.

Comment: The flavor text of that ability describes you as "_leading_" ambushes.  I take the implication to be that this is primarily for the benefit of your party.